# Using .htaccess to restrict visits to login page from all IP's except mine

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a simple PHP website with a login page url like
    http://sample.com/login

I need to restrict access to the login page from any IP addresses other than mine. But, I dont want to restrict access to any of the other pages on the site. I added the following code to the top of my .htaccess file, but it doesn't seem to be working correctly. Any help anyone can give me with the correct code to add to my .htaccess to only block access to /login/ from other IP's would be much appreciated!

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
RewriteRule ^/login/$ http://sample.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: Make it `RewriteRule ^/?login/?$ http://sample.com/ [L,R=301,NC]` and test in a different browser.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks anubhava!

Answer (score 2):

You could use `<Files ...>`, which would block that specific file from access from everywhere but a given IP, using `deny` and `allow`. This is a relative path, and this `.htaccess` should be placed in the same folder as your login-file.

```
<Files login.php>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
</Files>
```

Replace `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` with your IP. Remember that if you change IP-address (if its not static for example), this will not be a viable solution.

Comment: "This is a relative path" - there isn't actually a "path" at all.

Comment: Right, you get the idea though, even if the terminology is off. If you think you can improve the answer, there's an edit button you know ;-)